# Resetting a custom UITableViewCells content when its being reused

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using the following code to create a custom UITableViewCell with a label in it.

The problem I have is that the cell doesn't get cleared when it's reused and I'm unsure of how to do so as I don't think I have access to the cell contents when it's dequeued.

Can anyone tell me how I'd do this please?

```
if (indexPath.section == 2) {
    // Resetting the elements in the cell prior to use.

    UIView *blankCell;
    UILabel *methodText;

    static NSString *methodCellIdentifier = @"Method Cell";

    methodCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: methodCellIdentifier];

    if (methodCell == nil)
    {
        methodCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: methodCellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    blankCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    methodText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 305, 44)];
    methodText.text = [[self.recipeDict objectForKey:@"Method"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"methodText.text = %@", methodText.text);
    [methodText setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    [methodText setNumberOfLines:0];
    [methodText sizeToFit];

    [blankCell addSubview:methodText];
    [methodCell.contentView addSubview:blankCell];

    [methodText release];

    methodCell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;

    return methodCell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the code that creates your subviews inside the block that checks if methodCell is nil. Only update their content outside of that block. To access them outside the block, set tag values on them when creating them and use viewWithTag to find and update their content:

```
 if (methodCell == nil)
    {
        methodCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: methodCellIdentifier] autorelease];
        blankCell = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        methodText = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 7, 305, 44)];
        [methodText setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
        [methodText setNumberOfLines:0];
        [blankCell addSubview:methodText];
        [methodCell.contentView addSubview:blankCell];

        methodText.tag = 1;

        [methodText release];
        [blankCell release];

        methodCell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw;
    }

    methodText = (UITextField*)[methodCell viewWithTag:1];
    methodText.text = [[self.recipeDict objectForKey:@"Method"] objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"methodText.text = %@", methodText.text);
    [methodText sizeToFit];
```

Comment: While this worked well after I tried it I'm now seeing similar issues occur but I think it's related to the way I figure out the height of the cells generated by the code above. Any chance you could help with that?

Comment: Double checked and now it doesn't seem to work after all. Not sure what's happened.